# IsNull Or Blank Value replace by Zero(0) In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 and created a SQL query in which I first split the value and that records display in second table, but the problem is when there is a null value in the column, that record is not displayed in second table.

But I want that record with null or 0 value in second table.

I uploaded this screenshot of what I require for you to understand my question:

[image: I want Output like this]

Can anyone solve my problem and guide me?

Here is my Exactly Output
[Exactly Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR9wW.png)

Comment: Please show us your table schema, sample data from those tables and required result

Comment: You are filtering out the 'I0501AM' record, please check that. Also, use the left join with MetalDetails table.

Comment: i will try Left Outer Join in MetalDetails But Not Output Exactly

Comment: I Have Put Exactly Output Image https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR9wW.png  Please Check It @Squirrel

Comment: Can you just use case when? on that field? Case when Field = '' then 'string' else FieldName end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to `OUTER APPLY` and since the split is null, you will also need to use LEFT JOIN to `MetaDetails`

```
SELECT      TDCWax.TDCNo,
            TDCWax.MouldCode,
            ISNULL(MetaDetails.MetalName, 'For All Metal') as MetalName,
            TDCWax.Status
FROM        TDCWax
OUTER APPLY dbo.split(TDCWax.TDCMCode, '|') split
LEFT JOIN   MetaDetails ON MetaDetails.MetalCode = split.items
WHERE       TDCWax.MouldCode = 'I0501'
```

Comment: Not Giving my Output

Comment: what is your output ?